# Javascript/Jquery Prevent injections from executing code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting JSON data for a .getJSON function for Jquery. I am thinking of using .text to make the data safe (I believe this is the proper thing to do). I have tested and the JSON is correct.

Here is the script I am working on:

```
var firstpost = 0;
var firstrun = 0;
var lastpost = 0;
```

^ Global vars

```
        $.getJSON('chatget.php', {
    'chatroomid' : '<?php echo $chatroomid; ?>',
    'firstpost': firstpost,
    'lastpost': '1'},
    function(data) {
        var template = '<div id="_ID_" class="chatpost"> <div><b>_NAME_ </b> <a href="_URL_"> _USERNAME_ </a> _DATETIME_</div> <div><em>_TARGETS_</em></div> <div>_TEXT_</div> </div>';
        var appendhtml ='';

        var datarows = data['New'].length;
        lastpost = data['New'][datarows]['CPid'];

        // Each row processor               
        $.each(data['New'], function(index, col){

        // Get initial data
        if (firstrun == 0){
        firstpost = col.CPid;
        firstrun = 1;}

            // process targets
            if(col.Targets !== null){
                var target = col.Targets.split(',');
                var trow = target.length;
                var targets = '';
                for (var i=0, len=target.length; i<len; i++){

                    targets = targets + '@' + target[i] + ' ';}     
            }else {var targets = '';};

            // Append data to chatroom
            var cpid = $.text(col.CPid);
            var name = $.text(col.Name);
            var username = $.text(col.Username);
            var url = $.text(col.Url);
            var text = $.text(col.Text);
            var datetime = $.text(col.Datetime);
            var targets = $.text(targets);

            appendhtml = template.replace('_ID_',cpid).replace('_NAME_',name).replace('_USERNAME_',username).replace('_URL_',url).replace('_TEXT_',text).replace('_DATETIME_',date).replace('_TARGETS_', targets);

        $('#chatroom').append(appendhtml);
        });






        } // End Data function
    ) // End Get Json
```

For some reason since I changed some stuff in this code it is crashing firebug so either I found a bug in firebug or I did something very wrong in the coding. I don't think I am using $.text correctly...

Also I am trying to get the last value in the data['New'] object/array. .length doens't seem to be working.

```
            var datarows = data['New'].length;
        lastpost = data['New'][datarows]['CPid'];
```

This is my first javascript/Jquery program so if you see something wrong in the code please tell me.

Comment: Objects does'nt have a length, so it's not suprising that it does'nt work? And yes, you are using text() the wrong way, it's a method that you chain to an element. As for safe, it's not safe, and since it's clientside it's never going be to be safe, no matter what method you use?

Comment: Well safe for the average user. It is receiving information from the server that was input from a user. That input was never cleaned but it cannot be executed PHP side. I just want to prevent any html/scripts from being able to be executed before the data is appended. Once it is appended any scripts should appear as plain text.

Comment: Validating user input on the clientside really does'nt make it safe, at best it can make validation a little prettier for forms. You need to validate the data on the serverside before you send it back to the page.

Comment: @adeneo Alright I'm going to update stuff server side and retry this than.

Answer (score 1):

For best practice, encapsulate your code within an anonymouse wrapper function so that any functions or variables you create/used is inaccessible to outside environtment.

```
(function(){
    //your code
}())
```

NOTE: Google, jquery, etc all follow this system of practice!